# What is the difference between Named Entity Recognition and Named Entity Extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Please help me understand the difference between Named Entity Recognition and Named Entity Extraction.

Comment: They're the same thing.

Comment: Where did you see the term Named Entity Extraction? I've never heard of it. Do you mean Information Extraction?

Answer (score 1):

Named Entity Recognition is recognition of the surface form of an Entity (person, place, organization), i.e. "George Bush" or "Barack Obama" are "PERSON" entities in this text string.

Entity Extraction will extract additional information as attributes from the text string. For example in the sentence "George W. Bush was president before President Obama" recognizing "Obama" as a person with attribute "title=president".

But if you look at software the distinction is often blurred.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as Named Entity Extraction.
Paraphrasing better the sentence I would say that Named Entity Extraction is simple the process of concrete extracting previously recognized named entities. So, in a sense, there is no real theoretical knowledge that is relevant to this task, is just a matter of defining the mechanical operation.

If we are instead interested in extracting all the specific entities or the additional information regarding them from a piece text, than we have to look at **information** or **knowledge extraction**.

For information extraction you could for example ask to extract all the names of cities, or e-mail addresses, that appear in a corpus of documents. For such a task Named Entity Extraction could be used. You could even go much more generic, asking simply to extract general knowledge, for example in the form of relations (relation extraction).

For more details I would suggest the Natural Language Processing chapter of the book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern
Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/).